# Не получается преобразовать InputStream в String

Tags: java, android

Друзья, помогите, уже целый день не могу настроить полноценное API через `HttpURLConnection` и `java.net.URL`. Проблема в том, что не получается преобразовать `InputStream` в строку. Никаких Exception в консоли нет, на выходе получаю пустую строку. В логе nginx'a этот запрос так же отображается нормально.

Мой код:

Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gobonus.gobonus">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/GB">
        <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:parentActivityName=".WelcomeActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.gobonus.gobonus.WelcomeActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

WelcomeActivity

```
    package com.gobonus.gobonus;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        new AsyncRequest().execute("123", "/ajax/loginHandler.php", "foo=bar");

    }

    public void LoginGo(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    class AsyncRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private Request req;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            Request req = new Request(arg[0], arg[1], arg[2]);
            this.req = req;
            return req.Content;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            Log.d("Current Headers", String.valueOf(this.req.Headers));
            Log.d("Current Content", this.req.Content);
            TextView WebTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.webTest);
            WebTest.setText(s);
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.gobonus.gobonus.WelcomeActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="#B6B6B6"
        android:layout_marginBottom="162dp"
        android:onClick="LoginGo"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/reg"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:background="#B6B6B6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/webTest"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Request

```
package com.gobonus.gobonus;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class Request {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "GoBonus Android Client 1.0";
    private final String API_SERVER = "project.localhost";
    private final Integer API_PORT = 80;
    private final String API_PROTOCOL = "http";

    protected Map<String, List<String>> Headers;

    public String Content;



    public Request (String session_token, String uri, String params) {

        String urlParameters  = "session_token="+session_token+"&"+params; // url params
        byte[] postData       = new byte[0];

        System.setProperty("http.agent", USER_AGENT); // user agent

        // api < 19
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            postData = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
        }
        else
            postData = urlParameters.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        int    postDataLength = postData.length;
        URL    url            = null;

        try {
            url = new URL( API_PROTOCOL, API_SERVER, API_PORT, uri);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection conn= null;
        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        conn.setDoOutput( true );
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        try {
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));

        conn.setUseCaches( false );
        try {
            Log.d("request uri", url.toString());
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(postData);
            conn.connect();
            // after connect
            Content = ConvertData(conn);
            Headers = conn.getHeaderFields();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    protected String ConvertData (HttpURLConnection c) throws IOException {
        return this.convertStreamToString(c.getInputStream());
    }
    static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
03-24 20:29:44.904 8306-8306/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-24 20:29:45.092 8306-8327/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-24 20:29:45.095 8306-8306/? W/linker: gralloc.clovertrail.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x62a
03-24 20:29:45.095 8306-8306/? W/linker: libpvr2d.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x79b
03-24 20:29:45.095 8306-8306/? W/linker: libpvr2d.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
03-24 20:29:45.096 8306-8306/? W/linker: gralloc.clovertrail.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
03-24 20:29:45.097 8306-8306/? E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 27
03-24 20:29:45.097 8306-8306/? E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 28
03-24 20:29:45.097 8306-8306/? E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 28
03-24 20:29:45.097 8306-8306/? E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 28
03-24 20:29:45.108 8306-8326/? D/request uri: http://project.localhost:80/ajax/loginHandler.php
03-24 20:29:45.113 8306-8306/? D/Atlas: Validating map...
03-24 20:29:45.171 8306-8327/? E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 31
03-24 20:29:45.176 8306-8327/? E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 33
03-24 20:29:45.177 8306-8327/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-24 20:29:45.177 8306-8327/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
03-24 20:29:45.177 8306-8327/? W/linker: libPVROCL.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x9fd
03-24 20:29:45.178 8306-8327/? W/linker: libPVROCL.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
03-24 20:29:45.189 8306-8327/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-24 20:29:45.278 8306-8321/com.gobonus.gobonus I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1930(121KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 10.371ms total 50.765ms
03-24 20:29:45.298 8306-8306/com.gobonus.gobonus I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@233c3300 time:10120064
03-24 20:29:45.663 8306-8306/com.gobonus.gobonus D/Current Headers: {null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], Cache-Control=[no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0], Connection=[keep-alive], Content-Type=[text/html; charset=UTF-8], Date=[Thu, 24 Mar 2016 17:29:46 GMT], Expires=[Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT], Pragma=[no-cache], Server=[nginx/1.8.0], Set-Cookie=[PHPSESSID=c8lhojjp7na4jib3ka326vl506; path=/], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], X-Android-Received-Millis=[1458840585661], X-Android-Response-Source=[NETWORK 200], X-Android-Sent-Millis=[1458840585371], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block]}
```

Тесты провожу на API 22, в чем может быть проблема? Прошу сильно не пинать, на java я начал писать только сегодня

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так прочитать:

```
static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    return reader.ready() ? reader.readLine() : "";
}
```

Если не поможет, вероятно, у вас там действительно ничего нет, в этом InputStream.

Comment: Специально проверил, создал пустой файл, делаю к нему запрос и получаю `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. Методом тыка выяснил, что проблема возникает только если в файле 1 строка

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException означает, что файла нет по указанному пути. Советую поискать, что ещё менялось, кроме количества строк в файле.

Comment: Уже решил проблему. Дело было в том, что на бэкенде были редиректы, по которым скрипт не проходил. Спасибо